# How the Wronskian works

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, wronskian

To prove linear independence of a set of functions, we say that given their Wronskian matrix $~W~$, $~W_x = 0~$ implies trivial solution $~(0,0,0,\cdots)~$ if the value (determinant) of the Wronskian is identically non-zero.

But why so?

For all I know, $~W = 0~$ only implies a unique solution, not necessarily $~(0,0,0,\cdots)~$.

All the articles on the web are really confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you know that there is only one unique solution to the system. Can you try guessing it? It's pretty *trivial*...

Comment: I get your pont. But now I am wondering another thing. If in Ax = b, det(A) =  0, does it necessarily have to have either 0 or infinite solutions? Can the system have only two unique solutions?

Comment: @Sidd Over an infinite field (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) zero determinant implies no- or infinite amount of solutions.